# How to graph a list with days ( y: number of days x:day)

Tags: python, list, plot, graph

I need help about how to plot a list. I have a list with days (see image) and I need to make a graph, where the **x axis is the day** and the **y axis is the number of times that day is repeated.**

The format of the date is **day/month/year**

[list of days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llmxo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows the three steps for doing this. First creating a list of random dates. Next computing the repetitions. Finally plotting the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import choices, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



## create random date list
date_diff_days = choices(range(1,20), k = 50)
dates = [datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=i) for i in date_diff_days]


## compute repeated times
d = dict()
for date in dates:
    d[date] = d[date] = d[date]+1 if date in d else 1
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list(d.keys()),
                  'repeated' : list(d.values())})
df = df.sort_values(['date'])


## plot the timeseries data
plt.plot_date(x = df['date'], y = df['repeated'])
labels = [str(i.day) + '/'+ str(i.month) + '/'+str(i.year) for i in df['date']]
plt.xticks(ticks=df['date'],labels=labels, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```